# Juju fails to download the charm - dial tcp: lookup store.juju.ubuntu.com: no such host

Tags: networking, juju, downloads, maas

I'm trying to deploy juju gui on my maas controller but juju is unable to get the gui charm. This is the error I get:

```
ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 cannot download charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-16": 
Cannot access the charm store. Are you connected to the internet? 
Error details: Get https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fjuju-gui-16: dial tcp: lookup store.juju.ubuntu.com: no such host
```

Wget and everything else works for getting the charm, only juju fails to get the charm.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add if you're behind a proxy to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own post again. The problem was that the maas nodes didn't have network connectivity. I have turned maas controller into a gateway/router edited resolv.conf on every node and when I got internet connectivity through the maas controller and host resolution charms installed without a problem. I would recommend everyone who faces this problem in future that they check their nodes connectivity first and start from there.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yep, Juju needs to get the charms to the state server inside the MAAS nodes so they need internet access. Glad you got it sorted out.